# Private set class and its methods Swift 4

Tags: swift, swift4

I am trying to declare a type class private set variable but i would like to know how I can extend that to its properties.

I have:

```
class ClassA{
    var name:String?
}
```

Then In ClassB:

```
class ClassB{
private (set) aCLassA = ClassA()

}
```

That are the results I get in other class:

```
var classB = ClassB()
classB.aCLassA = ClassA() //-->Expected Error
classB.aClassA.name = "NewName" //--> I want that to give an error
```

Maybe it is a duplicate but I don't know which name it has

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `ClassA` is a reference type, you can think of this line:

```
private (set) var aCLassA = ClassA()
```

as if it says: "Only I (instance of ClassB) am allowed to change whatever `aClassA` points to".

Setting a property on the instance of `ClassA` that `aClassA` points to, does not mutate the pointer, it only mutates the instance itself which is not "detected" by `ClassB` because all it knows is that it still expects to find an instance of `ClassA` at the memory address `aClassA` points to.

You could mark all relevant attributes on `ClassA` as `private(set)` to get the behaviour you want. Alternatively, you can make `ClassA` a value type like `struct` so that an assignment to any of `ClassA`'s properties would cause the actual value of `aClassA` to change.

You can try this in a Playground to see the behavior:

```
struct ClassA {
  var name = "ClassA"
}

class ClassB {
  private(set) var aClassA = ClassA()
}


let b = ClassB()
b.aClassA.name = "Hello" // throws error
```

Comment: I get it know. Thank you very much

Comment: Just one more question. Does the struct theory apply to the tuples too, right?

Comment: Yes it does the same